# How to interpret the Message amplitude in ASTERIX CAT 021 out of an ADS-B receiver?

Tags: ads-b, asterix

As we know that the ADS-B use only in the reception so it's has own dynamic range.

The ADS-B ground station receives a signal from an aircraft and after the processing its will convert it to ASTERIX CAT021 formatted message.

When I checked the recording I noticed that the items I021/132 has the Amplitude message, in dBm, of ADS-B messages received by the ground station, coded in two’s complement.

And it's showing after deciding: -27 dBm

But when I convert it directly from Hex to Dec I found 0xE5 = 229.

What is the meaning here?

Comment: Could you be more specific with your question, than "what is the meaning here"?

Comment: IMHO, less on topic (or interesting) than the hijacker profile question.  VTC for lack of clarity per other comment, and no practical application to aviation.

Comment: Edit to tie this to a required maintenance function and I’d vote to reopen, otherwise it’s way too esoteric.  (Although you have a good answer now, so incentive is zero…)

Answer (score 3):

[ASTERIX Category 021](https://www.eurocontrol.int/sites/default/files/content/documents/nm/asterix/part2-cat021-asterix-ads-b-messages-part-12.pdf), Item 132 **Amplitude** is a one-octet (eight-bit) fixed-length data item encoded in [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

The octet `0xE5` (`11100101`) has the value $229_{10}$ if it is interpreted as a simple unsigned integer, but in two's complement it is interpreted as the decimal value $229-2^8 = 229-256 = -27\text{ dBm}$.